# How can I customize unity button swap animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I have **png sequence and mov format** of my animation, but I don't know how to add them to unity button swap animation.
What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with Transition Options in Button component. There are four types of transitions options right now. Have a look at this Unity docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-SelectableTransition.html)

[image]

Comment: so I can import my animation into unity, and make them into a sprite and add them to button swap animation?